# Augmented Reality 3D Model rendering

Tags: android, ios, opencv, augmented-reality, metaio

[image: Real Time circle shape]

In the above image I'm using OpenCV to detect circle shape. Next I want to display 3D circle objects rendered on such circular shapes.

Previously I have used MetaIO SDK, for marker based detection and it also does the 3D object rendering quite well.

Since OpenCV explains the image processing, various operators like Sobel/Canny, Hough Transform, Gaussian filtering etc quite properly, I used it to help me with markerless detection.

I am also able to detect square, quadrilateral, triangle. However I am stuck at the next part of my application i.e. 3D model rendering. For e.g. since the shape detected was a circle I would like to show this 3D Model below.

[image]

Please if anyone can can share some insight as to how this can be achieved? Even is it possible to integrate MetaIO and OpenCV to get close to meeting my requirement?

My application is to be used on both android and iOS devices.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try to contact this user http://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood

Comment: Done, thanks for the lead. :) Hope I get some help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL + OpenCV Augmented Reality on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919985/opengl-opencv-augmented-reality-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

When I was going through openCV tutorial, I bumped across following url... This one actually draws a polygon which has 3D effects...

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html#point-polygon-test

The 3D modelling can also be done using OpenGL interoperability... Following is the reference URL...

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/opengl_interop.html?highlight=opengl#general-information